# Hot to find what to target with wordpress theme-child codes?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have two problems. Site address: https://formationdialek.wp03.iciwordpress.com/

1. I'm trying to overwrite some code to get my navigation menu at that top to be closer left to the logo.
   There is a `float:right` property that I cannot overwrite:
   I tried to target the id, and the div, but it does not change anything.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px)
    .navbar-onex .navbar-nav {
        float: right;
    }
}
```

2. Same thing regarding the footer. I want it to be aligned left with the logo on top but can't overwrite the margin.

Comment: Link doesnt work :)

Comment: I guess it's because the site is hosted on a school 'private' server.  Is it ossible to upload a screenshot?

Comment: well, yea. therea re tons of ways you can do so. just use Google

Comment: I tried google search. I tried many different codes but nothing works.

Comment: I can help, but you gotta post your HTML and CSS in order for us to understand.